# With for loop, run a model across multiple pandas columns and create new columns with model output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For 4 columns in my dataframe, I'd like to run a model on each of these and append the results as 4 new columns to the original dataframe.

I currently have something like below:

```
materials = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4']
materials_new= ['found_new', 'walls_new', 'roof_new', 'floor_new']

for i, j in zip(materials, materials_new):
    df["%s"]=mlb.inverse_transform(grid_search_rf.predict(df[i])) % j
```

However this produced the error, "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'str'".

Any advice on how to create new dataframe column names with a for loop and list, would be great.

Side note: I'm able to run the model individually on the 4 columns to create new columns in the df, so I don't believe my error is related to the model. At some point I'll be repeating this exercise with 12+ columns, so I'm trying to pursue this for loop method.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try: `df[j]=mlb.inverse_transform(grid_search_rf.predict(df[i]))`

Comment: that was the solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i, j in zip(materials, materials_new):
    df[j]=mlb.inverse_transform(grid_search_rf.predict(df[i]))
```